# Resources for the Basics on Signals and Electromagnetic Waves in the radio frequencies

Tags: wave, radio

What are some good books and videos, to learn about radio waves?

For someone (me) who has never studied Math, Physics, or anything people generally consider ‘technical’.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about EM waves, not signal processing.

Answer (score 2):

A classic reference is "The Science of Radio", by Nahin; it's one of my favorite books on any topic. It does have a little bit of math -- there's just no way around it, but it is very well explained and makes few assumptions on your math background.